# sql search query still not producing expected results

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select

I need a count and search query to work properly. The count query appears to be working properly, however the search query is not.

Count query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tg_id) 
  FROM tg_keywords 
 WHERE tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' OR tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' 
 ORDER BY tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' AND tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2 DESC
Returns 1 count as expected.
```

Search query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tg_keywords.tg_id 
  FROM tg_keywords LEFT JOIN tg_info.tg_id=tg_keywords.tg_id 
 WHERE tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' OR tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' 
 ORDER BY tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' AND tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' DESC, tg_info.date_added LIMIT 16 OFFSET 1
Returns 0 results (1 is expected)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,
Archie

Comment: What do you mean by "not working correctly"?

Comment: The first query produces 1 result from the database as I wanted, but the second query returns 0 results. I wanted the first query to count the number of results with no limit, but the second query to return the unique tg_id field with a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove the `OFFSET 1` at the end of the query and then try it.**

The `OFFSET 1` tells it to give you records from the SECOND row. Either make it `OFFSET 0` or remove it altogether.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thought the OFFSET always started at 1. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tg_keywords.tg_id 
FROM tg_keywords 
LEFT JOIN tg_info.tg_id=tg_keywords.tg_id 
WHERE tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' OR tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' 
ORDER BY tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' AND tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' DESC, tg_info.date_added 
LIMIT 16 OFFSET 1
```

What's with that ORDER BY part?  Did you mean:

```
WHERE tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_1' OR tg_keyword LIKE 'keyword_2' 
ORDER BY tg_info.date_added DESC
```

Comment: no, I want the results that match all the keywords to be returned first. that's why the criteria is the same as above, but the AND operator is in between keywords instead of OR as above.

Answer (score 0):

Also do you want to give the user the ability to use SQL wildcards?  If not I probably ditch like and put in an =.